# extracting block of files from given two files

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk

I have two files as follows

cat file1.txt

```
256
258
```

cat file2.txt

```
2.1 56.8 85.1 256
2.2 56.8 85.2 256
2.3 56.8 85.3 256
2.4 56.8 85.4 258
2.5 56.8 85.5 258
```

I want to extract the block of file from file2.txt when the 4th column values of file2.txt matches with the value of file1.txt. I also want to skip blank lines from file1.txt in output.

Expected output, where it should create output files in following format.

first_block

```
2.1 56.8 85.1 256
2.2 56.8 85.2 256
2.3 56.8 85.3 256
```

second_block

```
2.4 56.8 85.4 258
2.5 56.8 85.5 258
```

My tried code is:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in `cat file1.txt' `
do
    ndt=$file
    echo $ndt
    for #here unable to proceed
done
```

But I am unable to match and extract the block of file. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please suggest a solution using for loop if possible

Comment: @user19520518, you need NOT to use `for` loop that's an overkill IMHO. `awk` can handle many things within itself, reading multiple files is one of them.

Comment: @user19520518, Also by getting blocks means, you want different output files? With same 1st column values? Please clarify on same.

Comment: awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
 @RavinderSingh13

Comment: yes i want different output file @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @user19520518, there was a typo(as this was written on mobile), try `awk 'FNR==NR{arr[0];next} ($NF in arr)'  file1 file2`.

Comment: nothing seen on terminal false run @RavinderSingh13

Comment: i want the blocks as output and lateron i will use it on other purposes

Comment: As for asking for a for loop - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
!NF{ next }
prev!=$NF{
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=(++count)"_block.txt"
}
{
  print > (outputFile)
  prev=$NF
}
' file1 <(sort -k4 -n file2)
```

***NOTE:*** In case you have GNU `sort` and you want to keep the order in which lines occurring then change `sort` command to `sort -s -k4 -n file2`

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```bash
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  arr[$0]                         ##Creating array arr with index of current line.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!NF{ next }
prev!=$NF{                        ##If prev is NOT equal to $NF value then do following.
  close(outputFile)               ##Closing output file here in backend.
  outputFile=(++count)"_block.txt" ##Creating outputFile variable with value of ++count followed by string _block.txt
}
{
  print > (outputFile)            ##printing current line into output file whose variable name is outputFile.
  prev=$NF                        ##Setting $NF value to prev.
}
' file1 <(sort -k4 -n file2)      ##mentioning file1 and file2 data as input.
```

Comment: error awk: cannot open "" for output (No such file or directory)

Comment: it is running fine for example data sets...if i have more rows in the input file it produces many blocks,which should produce only 2 blocks as file1 contain 2 rows can u please suggest a good solution  @Ravinder jii

Comment: @user19520518, this produces output files as per your file1's contents, how many unique ids will be there in file1 that many output files will be created.

Comment: @user19520518, Once you confirm this is working, I will add a detailed explanation for same.

Comment: i have two unique ids here may be it will increase while applying to large data sets

Comment: @user19520518, yes true, that is how it works, and it should work IMHO. Are you Good now?

Comment: no if i am applying to large data sets it produces number pg block files instead of just 2 block

Comment: Any other solution is highly appreaciated which should work for large data

Comment: @user19520518, see this is looking for whole line(in `file1`) AND last field(`$NF`) from `file1` as per your shown samples, are your unique values residing on same places in your actual files?

Comment: @user19520518, I am willing, ready to help; kindly do explain me more how and where this code is not working. With your shown samples this code is working well and fine.

Comment: jii please provide a link there i will upload my input file

Comment: @user19520518 does your `file2` contain blank lines?

Comment: no @tshiono it is continuous

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my input consists of 1000 lines of data where 700 lines contain unique id 256 and rest of the data contain unique id 258 on the 4rth column....when i am trying ur code for small data sets it works fine but for large data sets it runs ut produces many files ~50  .txt files, does ur code considers other column values  except 4th column values ???

Comment: @user19520518, see this is looking for whole line(in file1) AND last field($NF) from file1 as per your shown samples,

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I'm not sure if it solves but `sort -k2` should be `sort -k4`, right?

Comment: @user19520518, kindly do check my updated code once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: The only other thing I can imagine could cause the null output file name would be if the OP had a blank line somewhere in file2. The `sort` would move it to the top of the file, then prev WOULD be equal to $NF (both null) and the output file name wouldn't be set before the `print`. Otherwise - the OPs awk is broken or they have a bug in THEIR code.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it worked fine now...at the last line if space is there it appends the zero values

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 if i have space on the last line of file2 this code appends zero ..how to overcome this proble

Comment: @user19520518, so you want to ignore blank lines? correct

Comment: yes @RavinderSingh13, u r right

Comment: @user19520518, ok sure, edited the code now. Let me add this detail in your question also now.